# Deadlink scans crashed server behind a load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bitnami, google-cloud-load-balancer

**What I'm using**

- Bitnami Wordpress
- Unmanaged Instance Group
- Google Cloud Load Balancer (with health check and CDN enabled)

The web server crashed whenever I use a deadlink checker to scan the website that's behind the GCLB. The same tests conducted on the staging website without GCLB works fine.

1. Is it because of my health check configuration?
2. How can I prevent unauthorised third party scans on the server?

I've also set **Connection draining timeout** to be **300s**
.
.

[image]

Comment: What does **The web server crashed** mean? Details are required to help you.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley I have to restart the web server for it to work again.

Comment: There can be many reasons for that. You must investigate the details such as CPU usage, low memory, excessive swap space usage, etc. What does the Google Cloud Console GUI indicate? Tip: most likely you have selected a too small compute instance. What size are you using?

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley I have checked CPU usage, memory..etc which seems fine. I created an instance from a machine image and tried the same tests on a staging environment without the GCLB set up and it works fine.  I'm using an e2 standard 2 with 100GB disk capacity. The website is utilizing only 10% of disk capacity and is not a high performing website.